# Showing all rows and columns of Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, visual-studio-code

I am working with python 3 and the pandas package in visual studio code and I the print() function is not displaying correctly.

For example when I am using df.head() it looks good.

[image: df.head() example]

But If I use the print() statement I no longer see all of the columns next to each other, some of them get dragged down for some reason. And I can't see the entire data

[image: print(df) example]

Anyone knows what I can do to see the entire data, and all of the columns next to each other?

Comment: Don't use `print`. Just use `trading_history` without anything

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that does work. 

But I still cannot see the entire data.
I can only see the first 5 rows, the last 5 rows and the number of rows and columns I have.

Comment: print() is working, as documented. HTML table output is highly dependent on your notebook environment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem comes from library `pandas` that cuts part of your dataframe when it's too long. Before your `print`, add this line:

```py
pandas.set_option('max_row', None)
```

to display the entier row.

Also, you will be able to see all your data adding `None` argument in `head()`:

```py
trading.head(None)
```

UPDATE:

As pointed in the comments, for latest pandas versions, use instead:

```
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

And for columns:

```
pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

Comment: You are my hero, thanks a lot!

Comment: In more recent versions of Pandas I think this needs to be qualified to `pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', None)`

Comment: For ease of cut-n-paste `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None, 'display.max_colwidth', None)`